# Conflicts in library dependencies when updating to Play 2.6.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am updating from Play framework 2.5.x to 2.6.x and run into the following warnings when building:

```
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn] 
[warn]  * org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:0.33 is selected over 0.32
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web:1.4.3 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (depends on 0.32)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe:npm_2.10:1.2.1                        (depends on 0.32)
```

AND

```
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn] 
[warn]  * org.webjars.bower:jquery:2.2.4 is selected over {2.1.1, 1.6, 1.8, 1.2.2}
[warn]      +- org.webjars.bower:toastr:2.1.3                     (depends on 2.2.4)
[warn]      +- org.webjars.bower:jquery-mousewheel:3.1.13         (depends on 2.1.1)
[warn]      +- org.webjars.bower:jquery.scrollTo:2.1.2            (depends on 2.1.1)
[warn]      +- org.webjars.bower:kendo-ui-core:2016.2.504+Official (depends on 2.1.1)
[warn]      +- org.webjars.bower:jquery-ui:1.12.1                 (depends on 2.1.1)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:22.0 is selected over {19.0, 20.0, 15.0}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.11                 (depends on 22.0)
[warn]      +- com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE                    (depends on 15.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.9                  (depends on 15.0)
[warn]      +- org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11                 (depends on 20.0)
[warn]      +- com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0                      (depends on 19.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.8 is selected over {2.5.3, 2.4.20}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.11         (depends on 2.5.8)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.9          (depends on 2.5.8)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.11 ()   (depends on 2.4.20)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-ws-standalone_2.12:1.1.3    (depends on 2.5.3)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.8 is selected over 2.4.20
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.5.8 ()         (depends on 2.5.8)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.11                 (depends on 2.5.8)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.8 ()        (depends on 2.5.8)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.9                  (depends on 2.5.8)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.11 ()     (depends on 2.4.20)
[warn] 
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

The first warning regarding the jquery version seems unrelated to the next three. The weird thing about the next three is that it looks like it's trying to include two versions of the Play framework (2.6.11 and 2.6.9). I can't figure out why that might be.

Other possibly relevant information:

- I am on SBT version 0.13.16
- I have the Play framework version set to 2.6.11
- I am also including the following plugins: sbt-less v1.1.2, sbt-rjs v1.0.10, sbt-digest v1.1.4, sbt-gzip v1.0.2, sbt-play-ebean v4.1.0, sbt-play-enhancer v1.2.2

And here are the library dependencies in my build.sbt file:

```
    guice,
    openId,
    ws, 
    ehcache,
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.8",
    "commons-cli" % "commons-cli" % "1.2",
    "commons-collections" % "commons-collections" % "3.2.1",
    "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "3.3",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.1",
    "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
    "org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "2.0.4",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.9",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
    "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert-core" % "2.0M10",
    "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19",
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.1",
    "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.2.1",
    "org.webjars" % "qunit" % "2.1.0",
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.6.2",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "decimal.js" % "4.0.3",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "es6-promise" % "3.2.1",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "font-awesome" % "4.7.0",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "github-com-dataworker-dataworker" % "3.1.2",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "kendo-ui-core" % "2016.2.504+Official",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "knockout-sortable" % "0.15.0",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-mousewheel" % "3.1.13",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery.scrollTo" % "2.1.2",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-ui" % "1.12.1",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "toastr" % "2.1.3",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "knockout" % "3.4.2",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "stacktrace-js" % "2.0.0",
    "com.jcraft" % "jsch" % "0.1.54"
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect caching issue. Can you try removing the contents of `ivy` cache and trying to compile again? `rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/` ofcourse be careful when using `rm -rf` :)

Comment: Not related to your problems, but pdfbox is at 2.0.8 and not 2.0.4.

Comment: Any solution for this one? How your `build.sbt` and its related `views` (where you include the css/js assets) parts looks like?